# Does Linux's rsyslog support RFC 5424?

Tags: linux, syslog, rsyslog

For some reason, **rsyslogd** does not seem to be able to properly interpret a valid `RFC 5424` message. Even the example given by the RFC does not work:

```
$ echo "<165>1 2003-08-24T05:14:15.000003-07:00 192.0.2.1 myproc 8710 - - %% It's time to make the do-nuts." | nc -w1 -Uu /dev/log
```

results in a log line:

```
Dec  1 16:39:08 host 1 2003-08-24T05:14:15.000003-07:00 192.0.2.1 myproc 8710 - - %% It's time to make the do-nuts.
```

Which is an indication that message could not be interpreted properly as `RFC 5424` message and instead the whole string was considered to be a message payload.

On the other hand, the old `RFC 3164` format is accepted without problems:

```
$ echo "<165>Dec  1 05:14:15 myproc[8710]: %% It's time to make the do-nuts."| nc -w1 -Uu /dev/log
```

results in a correct log line:

```
Dec  1 16:44:31 host myproc[8710]: %% It's time to make the do-nuts.
```

Digging around the internet I couldn't find any mentions about the absence of support on the **rsyslog** side. Am I doing something wrong?

I'm running Linux Mint 20. **rsyslogd** version is `8.2001.0 (aka 2020.01)`

Could it be the fault of **systemd** that is somehow modifies the message content before it arrives to **rsyslog**?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Confused with syslog message format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209130/confused-with-syslog-message-format).  TL;DR: most *nix loggers use RFC 3164. rsyslogd, however, will allow you to configure RFC 5424 format

Comment: Not at all. That question is about the format of data stored in log files. My question is about the communication protocol between client and `rsyslog` service.

Comment: Q: "communication protocol between the client and the log service"?  Q: Aren't you just using the [syslog()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) standard library function?  Or are you doing "something else"?  Where exactly are you "blocked"?

Comment: @paulsm4 I'm not using **libc**'s library function `syslog()`. `RFC 5424` is an open protocol, As you can see from my question, I'm sending datagrams directly to `/dev/log` using `nc`.

Comment: It may be an issue with your `rsyslog` version. I tried it `echo "<165>1 2003-08-24T05:14:15.000003-07:00 192.0.2.1 myproc 8710 - - It's time to make 5424 do-nuts." | sudo nc -w1 -u 127.0.0.1 514` and it printed in the `/var/log/messges` like this: ```Aug 24 05:14:15 192.0.2.1 myproc[8710] It's time to make 5424 do-nuts.```. I am using RHEL 7.6 and `rsyslog` version is `rsyslog-8.24.0-57.el7_9.x86_64`.

Comment: @SoumyaKanti, hmm, interesting. Can you please also tell me if you're using **systemd**? To make sure it's not a systemd shenanigans.

Comment: @GreenScape Yes - I am using `systemd`.

Comment: @SoumyaKanti, thanks a lot for help, then it's not **systemd**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had the same issue, finally found out a solution by adding this to my rsyslog.conf :

```
input(type="imuxsock" socket="/dev/log" useSpecialParser="off")
```

The useSpecialParser parameter instructs imuxsock input module to use the regular parser for messages, instead of a special parser which is unable to parse RFC5424 format. Cf. https://rsyslog-doc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/modules/imuxsock.html

Note that for other input modules such as udp or tcp, RFC5424 is always parsed properly.

Comment: Rainer Gerhards, on why this is not an issue : https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/issues/4749

Answer (score 4):

The situation is pretty well covered here: [Confused with syslog message format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209130/confused-with-syslog-message-format).

TL;DR:

- most *nix loggers use RFC 3164.
- rsyslogd, however, will allow you to configure RFC 5424 format

Here is one of many articles that discusses how:

> [Generating the Syslog specific to RFC
> 5424](http://docs.ruckuswireless.com/fastiron/08.0.70/fastiron-08070-monitoringguide/GUID-88F338BA-B7BF-485C-B1DE-7418710452A6.html)
>
> By default, Syslog is generated in accordance with RFC 3164. To
> provide the maximum amount of information in every Syslog in a
> structured format, you can enable Syslog logging specific to RFC 5424.
>
> The Syslog that conforms to RFC 5424 has an enhanced Syslog header
> that helps to identify the type of Syslog, filter the Syslog message,
> identify the Syslog generation time with year and milliseconds with
> respect to the time zone, and other enhancements. The Syslog specific
> to RFC 5424 can be enabled using the `logging enable rfc5424` command.
> Logging buffer must be cleared before enabling Syslog specific to RFC
> 5424, otherwise the system displays an error.

---

Per the OP:

> My question is about the communication protocol between client and
> rsyslog service
>
> I'm not using libc's library function syslog()... I'm sending
> datagrams directly to /dev/log using nc

In which case, the solution appears to be to send the datagrams in standard RFC 3164 format.

One long-shot possibility:

> https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/concepts/messageparser.html
>
> Message parsers are a feature of rsyslog 5.3.4 and above.
>
> [They] are the component of rsyslog that parses the syslog message
> after it is being received. Prior to rsyslog 5.3.4, message parsers
> where built in into the rsyslog core itself and could not be modified
> (other than by modifying the rsyslog code).
>
> In 5.3.4, we changed that: message parsers are now loadable modules
> (just like input and output modules). That means that new message
> parsers can be added without modifying the rsyslog core, even without
> contributing something back to the project.

Comment: It does not seem to answer my question at all. Your link leads to Rukus documentation, where they explain how to configure their **clients** of syslog. My question is about the **rsyslogd** Linux service.

Comment: Your update does not answer my question either. I want to figure out what's wrong, not to ignore the problem and use ancient protocol. Even the Wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsyslog#Protocol of **rsyslog** says that `RFC 5424` is supported. But why isn't it working?